# authlogic_facebook_connect not skipping users validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, authlogic

im running rails 2.3.8, authlogic 2.1.6 and the extension for facebook connect (https://github.com/studybyte/authlogic_facebook_connect)

the facebook side is working good, user click on facebook connect button, goes to facebook, logs in and returns to my app.

my problem is very simple but i cant figure it out. when user is redirected to my site after logging in, if is a new user, i create a new record. Since it comes from facebook the user has no email or password but the user is not saved because authlogic fails password and email validation.

the authlogic_facebook_connect shouldnt skip these validations?

Answer (score 0):

i realized that i don't have to create a user, the plugin is supposed to do that for you. You just have to login the user after he connects to facebook.

It didnt work before because a did not create the facebook_session_key field but facebook_access_token instead.

Answer (score 0):

It should. It's supposed to call save(:validate => false) (in Rails 3.1 or save_with_validation(false) for older version if I remember correctly) to skip  the validations.